# MPX2200DP signal value reversed when amplified with AD620

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, pressure

I am trying to measure differential pressure with MPX2200DP. According to the datasheet, the signal is linear and its value ranges from 0 to 40 mV. To be able to use the sensor properly, AD620 instrumentation amplifier is used to amplify the signal to the sensor. The gain is chosen to be 100, and the reference terminal is not connected.
The measured signal show that the output voltage is reversed (i.e. Vout is 4.7 at zero pressure difference) and the it decreases with increasing pressure difference.
If the reference terminal is connected, Vout is dropped to 0.65 volts, and the value remains constant.

IS there any solution that could be applied?
[image: the attached photo is a reference schematic]

Comment: What is the supply voltage? What voltages do measure on and between +vout and -Vout, with and without the pressure differential?

Comment: According to the datasheet, the supply voltage is from 10 to 16 volt dc.
the voltage between Vout+ and Vout- is +4.7 volt, without pressure differential.
with pressure differential, the voltage decreases